# Le néologisme « international »

Tags: sens, prépositions, noms, néologismes

Dans un titre d'article d'aujourd'hui  dans le [Huffington Post](https://www.msn.com/fr-fr/actualite/monde/macron-disserte-sur-la-chine-et-les-%C3%A9tats-unis-et-s-attire-les-critiques-%C3%A0-l-international/ar-AA19G8ts?ocid=msedgdhp&pc=U531&cvid=0fd180f2911840b78524a88e9135d923&ei=50), se trouve le mot « international », qui doit être un néologisme d'introduction récente, et un nom masculin.

> Le Huffington Post — Macron disserte sur la Chine et les États-Unis et s’attire les critiques à l’international

Il n'est reconnu ni par le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/international), ni par le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/international). L'[internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/international/) n'a pas de définition non plus.

Néanmoins, il y a la définition suivante dans le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/international/43762).

> nom masculin
>
> 1. Domaine des relations internationales, spécialement dans les échanges commerciaux.
> 2. Dans une entreprise, secteur chargé de ce domaine : Travailler à l'international.
>    Domaine des relations internationales, spécialement dans les échanges commerciaux.

Peut-on se fier à la définition du Larousse relativement à ce titre ? On voit ensuite dans l'article qu'il s'agit de la scène internationale, ce qui semble faire référence à des critiques sur le plan politique venant de l'étranger, pas de la France, et même peut-être pas des pays européens, et pas du tout relatifs aux échanges commerciaux.

Il semble que ce soit insuffisant pour délimiter précisément le sens dans le titre ci-dessus. Comment comprendre ce mot ? Les critiques sont-elles à comprendre comme venant des divers intéressés en charge des relations internationales pour l'état français, ou bien viennent-elles des divers états qui ont des relations avec la France ? Est-on dans la nécessité d'attendre le corps du texte pour décider qu'il s'agit d'une chose plutôt que d'une autre ?

Une phrase comme la suivante, par exemple,

- « Il y a dans l'international de sérieux problèmes de communication. »

peut-elle être comprise comme

- « Il y a dans le domaine des relations internationales de sérieux problèmes de communication. » ?

Est-il souhaitable de remplacer ainsi cette expression ?

S'il fallait utiliser l'expression qui définit ce mot comment dirait on ? utiliserait-on « à » ou « dans » ? Est-ce que le passage de « dans » à « à » ne cause pas de problème ?

- Macron disserte sur la Chine et les États-Unis et s’attire les critiques au domaine des relations internationales.
- Macron disserte sur la Chine et les États-Unis et s’attire les critiques dans le domaine des relations internationales.

Answer (score 7):

***À l'international*** signifie ici tout simplement ***à l'étranger***.

C'est une formule très courante que [l'Académie n'aime pas](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/linternational) :

> Le 10 juillet 2012
> Extensions de sens abusives
>
> *À l’international* est une formule elliptique en usage dans la langue du commerce : *Prospective, travail, mobilité à l’international.*
> Cette construction s’étend abusivement. ***À l’international*** est trop souvent employé pour *À l’étranger*. ***Un billet de train valable en France et à l’international. Quand dit-on à l’international ? Quelles sont les réactions à l’international ?***

J'y soupçonne une coquille pour ***Qu'en dit-on à l'international ?***

Comment: Ah ! Très bonne résolution de la question, du moins pour ce qui est de l'essentiel. Si seulement j'avais pu penser que l'Académie a eu son mot à dire !

Comment: @LPH Pas de néologisme ici, ou bien "néologisme" à l'échelle de quelques décennies peut-être. En tout cas bien utilisé au quotidien, et tant pis pour l'Académie, comme d'habitude :-)

Comment: @Frank Quatre décennies au moins (le TLFi date de 1994) et toujours représenté dans les dictionnaires aussi pauvrement que le montre mes vérifications ? Il n'est vraiment pas aimé !

Comment: @LPH *Que le **montrent** mes vérifications.*

Comment: @jlliagre Évidemment, je sais bien ça, mais en écrivant on croit d'abord utiliser un sujet singulier, puis en y pensant un peu on se décide pour un sujet pluriel, et on a oublié le verbe qui se trouve derrière.

Comment: @LPH Quelque chose te chiffonne dans ma réponse pour que tu l'aie désacceptée ?